# Why does 'with' method doesn't work in Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline

I want to assign multiple values of object by using "with" method, available in groovy.
When I run it in local Groovy code, there is no problem, but when same code is run in Jenkins pipeline, suddenly, any of object properties are not being assigned.

I've went through differences that are brought by running code in Jenkins Pipelines, but there was no mention about problems with multiple-assignment

I have base class

```
class Car {
    private String colour
    private int tankCapacity

    String getColour() { return this.colour }

    int getTankCapacity() { return this.tankCapacity }

    String toCustomString() {
        return "Car colour: ${this.colour}, tank capacity: ${this.tankCapacity}"
    }
}
```

Usage in local script:

```
class App {
    static void main(String[] args) {
        Car car = new Car()
        car.with {
            colour = "Black"
            tankCapacity = 50
        }

        println "Printing car details:"
        println car.toCustomString()
        println "Colour: ${car.getColour()}"
        println "Tank capacity: ${car.getTankCapacity()}"
        println car.toString()
        println GroovySystem.version
    }
}
```

Usage in Jenkins Pipeline step

```
def call(String arg_colour, int arg_tankCapacity) {
    Car car = new Car()
    car.with {
        colour = arg_colour
        tankCapacity = arg_tankCapacity
    }

    echo "Printing car details:"
    echo car.toCustomString()
    echo "Colour: ${car.getColour()}"
    echo "Tank capacity: ${car.getTankCapacity()}"
    echo car.toString()
    echo GroovySystem.version
}
```

And call in Jenkinsfile

```
createCar("Black", 50)
```

Output from local run is:

```
Printing car details:
Car colour: Black, tank capacity: 50
Colour: Black
Tank capacity: 50
myApp.Car@5d47c63f
2.4.12
```

Output from Jenkins Pipeline run is:

```
Printing car details
[Pipeline] echo
Car colour: null, tank capacity: 0
[Pipeline] echo
Colour: null
[Pipeline] echo 
Tank capacity: 0
[Pipeline] echo
org.mojcik.Car@504bcec3
[Pipeline] echo
2.4.12
```

Only way to actualy make it work in Jenkins is to use "it" before any field name, bit it doesn't make any sense and break an idea of "with" method.

```
Car car = new Car().with {
    it.colour = arg_colour
    it.tankCapacity = arg_tankCapacity
    return it
}
```

Anyone ever faced that?

Comment: create methods `setColor(String)` and `setTankCapacity(int)` that sets corresponding private members. i believe it does not work in jenkins because members are private

Comment: @daggett Unfortunately, switching those to public doesn'n make any difference. I know how to workaround this in few ways, but it bugs me, why 'with' merhod doesn't work in Jenkins pipeline

Comment: @daggett This exame is just showing general problem. In Real life application my class have over 10 attributes to be set. Initially I made that with setters as you suggested (and it worked) , but then codenarc complained about it, saying that i have to use 'with' or 'identity'.

Comment: probably connected with this: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-51166

Comment: as workaround you could use constructor with map: `new Car(colour: "red", tankCapacity: 50)` or implement own with method

Comment: Very frustrating bug, as because of it, it is impossible to import all methods to the script like `script_name.with { /* all methods of the script */ }`...

Comment: Unfortunately, I still haven't found solution to this :(